# How to skip 10 steps in Bootstrap Tour?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I have a situation, when I have a tour containing eleven steps.

In each step the popup contains "Prev", "Next", "End Tour" buttons.
Instead of using "End Tour" to "skip", I try to skip all the steps and go to the 11th step, but I can't get this to work.

```
steps: [
    {
        element: "#mobile",
        title: "Mobile Number",
        content: "Click ‘Next’ to view the next search field, Click ‘Previous’ to view the previous search field and click ‘skip’ to select End result.",
        placement: "right",
        backdrop: true,
        orphan: true,
        template: function (step) {
            return "<div class='popover tour'><div class='arrow'></div><h3 class='popover-title'></h3><div class='popover-content'></div><div class='popover-navigation'><button class='btn btn-xs btn-pink' data-role='prev'>« Prev</button><span>&nbsp;</span><button class='btn btn-xs btn-danger' data-role='next'>Next »</button><span>&nbsp;</span><button class='btn btn-xs btn-success' data-role='skip'>Skip</button> </div>   </nav>  </div>"
        },
        onNext: function () {
            dir = 'next';
        },
        onPrev: function () {
        },
        onShown: function () {
        }
    }
]
```

Here i am using data-role as "skip ".and how can i use this as a function like that `onShow()`, `onEnd()`, etc.

I tried `goTo(i)` method also not working.

Comment: First that is weird - are they really orpans? If yes - would you be so kind and try to simulate it in JSfiddle or something - like http://jsfiddle.net/marshals/2Q2UW/ - it would probably be easyer for us :)

Comment: Sir...here i am adding some changes in jsfiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/2Q2UW/5/                                 here just put some sample step..i need skip option here,when i click skip button goto the last step of the tour .this one i wanted sir..

Comment: Could this (http://jsfiddle.net/x2gex4gg/) do the job :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after reading DOCs - there is no method out-of-box to do skip steps.

But we can very easily build our own.

---

**Simple solution** (for exactly this scenario with 3 steps):

1.) add button role skip (our, new, role):

```
<button class='btn btn-xs btn-success' data-role='skip'>Skip</button>
```

2.) write method for skipping that catches skip button click:

```
$("body").on("click","button",function(){
    if($(this).attr("data-role") === 'skip'){
        alert("skip pressed :)");
        tour.goTo(2);        
    }
});
```

---

**Less simple solution** (for all scenarios):

1.) add buttons with role skip (our, new, role):

```
<button class='btn btn-xs btn-success' data-role='skip'>Skip</button>

...

<button class='btn btn-xs btn-success' data-role='skip'>Skip</button>

...

<button class='btn btn-xs btn-success' data-role='skip'>Skip</button>

...

etc
```

2.) have a method to:
a.) find all steps
b.) catch clicked button (skip) and it's step number (let's say x))
c.) goTo step x+1

---

**Advanced solution**:

extend Jquery plugin and add cross-scenario code to it

Answer (score 0):

you can use this below code to achive this , For me its working

```
 onNext: function(tour){
  var curr=parseInt(tour.getState("current_step"));
  while(true){
    curr+=1;
    var step=tour.getStep(curr);
    //TODO: check if it's undefined
    if($(step.element).length){
      tour.goto(curr);
      return curr;
    }
  }
},
onPrevious: function(tour){
  var curr=parseInt(tour.getState("current_step"));
  while(true){
    curr-=1;
    var step=tour.getStep(curr);
    //TODO: check if it's undefined
    if($(step.element).length){
      tour.goto(curr);
      return curr;
    }
  }
}
```